# Magic mouse USB cable

Tags: usb, mouse

I LOVE my Magic Mouse.  Unfortunately, at a new job, I can only used wired mice, NOT wireless (security issues).

Is there anything equivalent to the Magic Mouse, but uses a USB cable (for Emission Security)??  I'd really like something with a touchpad feel (NO scroll wheel!) in a mouse, that works for Mac and Windoze 10.

Comment: Please share what you have found already and why it does not work for you as recommendations generally are off topic. Guidance on what is on topic can be found here http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Security issues with wireless mice? Apparently mousejacking is [a thing.](https://www.swordshield.com/blog/mousejack-wireless-mouse-keyboard-vulnerable/) This linked article from last year has a list of susceptible mice, with Logitech and Microsoft models foremost.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a wireless USB mouse (uses 500 Hz or so) and comes with a little mini USB that you can use to plug-in to the PC. Logitech has a couple like this, you may have to look around for some.

But if you are looking for one for a Magic Mouse, you won't find one.

If you are concerned about accessing all of the Magic Mouse features with a wired/wireless (USB) mouse then I recommend finding one that uses gestures or has multiple buttons (like a gaming mouse).